# How to identify if consecutive numbers exist from a set of numbers from different columns in a table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am using SQL Server 2014 and have a table (`t1`). Extract is shown below:

```
Id    n1   n2    n3    n4    n5    n6
-------------------------------------
100   5    10    15    21    22    30
121   1     6    14    31    35    37
126   4     5    22    27    28    38
...
```

I need a new column `Consecutive` which tags each row in the table as a "Yes" or a "No".

Expected output:

```
Id    n1   n2    n3    n4    n5    n6  Consecutive
--------------------------------------------------
100   5    10    15    21    22    30      Yes
121   1     6    14    31    35    37      No
126   4     5    22    27    28    38      Yes
...
```

Note: all rows of n1 to n6 are in ascending order.

How can I do this using T-SQL?

Comment: what is the logic behind `Consecutive` column?

Comment: If any of 6 numbers (n1 to n6) have consecutive numbers then it is a "Yes"else a "No"

Comment: Could you please explain in detail. In what manner you are identifying as consecutive

Comment: @JimMacaulay In Row 100, we have n4 and n5 as consecutive numbers, in Row 126 we have n1 and n2 as and also n4 and n5 as consecutive numbers. No consecutive numbers in Row 121. I should add that all rows of n1 to n6 are in ascending order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do also the following

```
SELECT T.*, CASE WHEN 1 IN(N2-N1, N3-N2, N4-N3, N5-N4, N6-N5)
                 THEN 'Yes'
                 ELSE 'No'
            END Consecutive
FROM
(
    VALUES
    (100,   5,    10,    15,    21,    22,    30),
    (121,   1,     6,    14,    31,    35,    37),
    (126,   4,     5,    22,    27,    28,    38)
) T(Id, N1, N2, N3, N4, N5, N6);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with `case` statement. Here is the [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/88973/1).

```
select
    *,
    case
        when (n1 + 1 = n2 
        or  n2 + 1 = n3         
        or  n3 + 1 = n4
        or  n4 + 1 = n5
        or  n5 + 1 = n6) then 'Yes'
        else 'No'
    end as consecutive
from myTable
```

output:

```
| Id  | n1  | n2  | n3  | n4  | n5  | n6  | consecutive |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | ----------- |
| 100 | 5   | 10  | 15  | 21  | 22  | 30  | Yes         |
| 121 | 1   | 6   | 14  | 31  | 35  | 37  | No          |
| 126 | 4   | 5   | 22  | 27  | 28  | 38  | Yes         |
```